# Setting vector layer custom properties using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, labeling

I'm trying to set some labels and styles for some vector layers that are loaded programatically from a Spatialite database. I have the following code, which returns no error, and includes the changes in the .qgis file, but does not show on the canvas:

```
uri = QgsDataSourceURI()  
uri.setDatabase(database_path)
uri.setDataSource('', table_name, 'geometry')
layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), display_name, 'spatialite')
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled", "true")  
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontFamily", "Arial")
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fontSize", "10")
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/fieldName", "source_id")
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/placement", "2")
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 4):

You have to set the custom property that enables labeling in the first place.

```
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling", "pal")
layer.setCustomProperty("labeling/enabled", True)
```